# Container Managed Security, Spring Security and Authentication

Tags: spring, security, tomcat, spring-security, containers

I have been looking everywhere on how I can implement Spring Security based on a Container Managed Security Model.  In my test case, I am using Tomcat and it's corresponding tomcat-users.xml file.  The issue is, I cannot get Spring Security to play well (meaning pass authentication over to Tomcat) to let the app server perform the Authentication and have Spring manage the role based security once someone is authenticated. I am using the latest Spring versions, so it's all Java config as I am just not familiar enough with XML based config.  I have read many examples that talk about using a PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider but the examples are poor not to mention the Spring documentation is quite confusing IMHO. I even downloaded the sample preauth code from the Spring Security GIT hub but I still cannot see how the example code is tied to the authentication that Tomcat is performing.  When I run the Spring sample code for preauth, it doesn't authenticate with any of the users in my tomcat-users XML file as I deployed my code to Tomcat 8.  Wondering if anyone has any ideas on where I can look in order to understand how Spring Security and the authentication performed by Tomcat (container managed) happens?

**UPDATE:**
It appears I had to start from scratch and simply get the authentication to work with a very simply app created in my IDE.  Basically I had a folder that was called secure, one folder that was called unsecure and I mapped the paths according to the Servlet 3 spec to secure and unsecure what I needed.  I had to use a web.xml in order to contain the security constraints.  Once I tested in both Tomcat 7 and 8, where I tried to hit a secure URL, I was challenged to enter an ID and password.  Please note you have to define the path to a login page, mine was a simple JSP.  I also had to submit to the j_security_check and also make sure to use the j_username and j_password field names.  Once I knew I could hit a secure page, I then started introducing the Spring components.  This involved Spring Security, Spring Boot etc.  The key was in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.  Where I normally would have basic auth or form based security enabled, I removed those and instead used the jee() setting based on the same fluent builder API used to configure your security settings.  I left all antmatcher settings in the web.xml, so my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter was very basic.  When you are debugging controllers, you can inject the HttpServletRequest directly in the method and that request contains a userPrincipal request value containing things such as the user ID, and roles.  Good luck, hope this helps others because it was painfully long for me to figure out such a simple solution.

Comment: Man, thank you so much for this. I was banging my head against the wall for two days, trying to make Spring Security play nice with container authentication, and all I needed was to call .jee() method!

Comment: @arrgh where did you call jee() method?

Answer (score 3):

See the update for a detailed explanation on my solution.