# Spring Boot container authentication with standalone Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a standalone Tomcat server which should run my Spring Boot application (deployed as a `.war` file). This application needs to be secured with container authentication from Tomcat. First it should use the `tomcat-users.xml` in the development environment. In the production environment this realm will be replaced by another authentication method.

My configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test/test2").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
                .jee().mappableRoles("USER");
    }

}
```

Tomcat users:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd" version="1.0">
    <user username="testuser" password="pw" roles="user" />
</tomcat-users>
```

On secured pages the form login appears like expected, but the authentication does not work (Your login attempt was not successful, try again.).

Is something else missing in the configuration?

Log:

```
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
09:53:40 DEBUG w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
09:53:40 DEBUG w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@22ea93f6. A new one will be created.
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@738151d2
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /login' doesn't match 'GET /logout
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /login' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /login' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter'
09:53:40 DEBUG p.j.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter : Checking secure context token: null
09:53:40 DEBUG p.j.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter : PreAuthenticated J2EE principal: null
09:53:40 DEBUG p.j.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter : No pre-authenticated principal found in request
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
09:53:40 DEBUG w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Request is to process authentication
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User 'testuser' not found
09:53:40 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
09:53:40 DEBUG w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

Comment: First, you need to choose if you are using httpBasic or formLogin, if you are using your own form login then get rid of httpBasic, and, get rid of the .jee()   let's start with that.

Comment: One more thing to mention, you are not specifying against what you do your authentication, I mean if you are using a DB and you are authenticating users against it,  then you need to mention it.

Comment: It seems that you are missing basic understanding with spring security, try to learn it better and then go back to your project. best of luck

Comment: I am not specifying it, because the authentication should happen over the container (tomcat). That is why I added the `.jee()`. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/preauth.html

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any ultimate solution for this, but [this hint helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36777959/7090808) to make it work at all. It seems that a minimum of a `web.xml` is needed to "activate" the container authentication. Then Spring Security can handle this as pre authentication.

Unfortunately in this solution the authorities (roles) from the container authentication are not present. Therefore I had to remove Spring Security entirely and work only with the `web.xml` (and `context.xml`).

Comment: i also actually used container authenitcation with spring security, and in the web.xml i added the 'security-role' tag  with the role name inside, and also 'security-constraint' tags with the <web-resource-collection> inside and that's it